# How do I dynamically get an object type and cast to it?

Tags: vb.net, directcast

How do I get the object type so I can directly cast to it? This is the ideal method I would like to execute:

```
Dim MyObjects As New List(Of Object)
For Each O As Object In GlobalFunctions.GeneralFunctions.FindControlsRecursive(MyObjects, Form)
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf O Is MenuStrip Or TypeOf O Is ToolStripButton Or TypeOf O Is Panel Or TypeOf O Is Label Or TypeOf O Is ToolStripSeparator
            AddHandler DirectCast(O, O.GetType).Click, AddressOf GotFocus
    End Select
Next
```

I am trying to make the code more efficient so that I do not have to directly cast to a specified object type. Ex.:

```
Dim MyObjectsAs New List(Of Object)
For Each O As Object In GlobalFunctions.GeneralFunctions.FindControlsRecursive(MyObjects, Form)
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf O Is MenuStrip
            AddHandler DirectCast(O, MenuStrip).Click, AddressOf GotFocus
        Case TypeOf O Is Panel
            AddHandler DirectCast(O, Panel).Click, AddressOf GotFocus
        Case TypeOf O Is ToolStripButton
            AddHandler DirectCast(O, ToolStripButton).Click, AddressOf GotFocus
        Etc...
    End Select
Next
```

---

## EDIT

To my knowledge, a `ToolStripItem` (*ToolStripButton*) is not a `Control` so I cannot use a `List(Of Control)` for this situation. When I first was using a list of controls, the toolstrip items were not being included. This is the first time I have used `ToolStrip` in an application so I never had a reason for not using `List(Of Control)` until now.

Comment: `Dim MyObjectsAs New List(Of Control)`?

Comment: in most cases I do just use `List(Of Control)`, however, `ToolStripButton` doesn't get included into the list. So my way around that was to make a `List(Of Object)` and include everything in there. @GSerg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All controls derive from `Control`. Therefore, instead of using the type `Object` use `Control`. `Control` has most of the members of these controls like a `Click` event.

```vb
Dim myControls As New List(Of Control)
For Each ctrl As Control In _
  GlobalFunctions.GeneralFunctions.FindControlsRecursive(myControls, Form)

    AddHandler ctrl.Click, AddressOf GotFocus
Next
```

Use `Control` in `FindControlsRecursive` as well.

See:

- [Control Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=net-5.0)
- [VB.NET Polymorphism](https://riptutorial.com/vb-net/learn/100043/polymorphism)
- [Inheritance Basics (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/inheritance-basics)

---

It turned out that you have some components not being controls. But you can still cast all controls to `Control`

```vb
Dim myControls As New List(Of Object)
For Each obj As Object In
        GlobalFunctions.GeneralFunctions.FindControlsRecursive(myControls, Form)

    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf obj Is Control
            AddHandler DirectCast(obj, Control).Click, AddressOf GotFocus
        Case TypeOf obj Is ToolStripItem
            AddHandler DirectCast(obj, ToolStripItem).Click, AddressOf GotFocus
    End Select
Next
```

Note that `ToolStripItem` includes `ToolStripButton`, `ToolStripControlHost`, `ToolStripDropDownItem`, `ToolStripLabel` and `ToolStripSeparator`, since all of these components derive from `ToolStripItem`. You can see this in the Object Browser in Visual Studio:
[image]

`MenuStrip` is a `Control`. So, these two cases should cover most of your controls and components. If you find another component not covered here, search for its least derived base type featuring the `Click` event, so that the new case covers as many components as possible.

Comment: I know that a `Control` is a derivative of `Controls`, but I believe `ToolStripButton` and `ToolStripItem` are not a controls so they will not get be included in a List(Of Control). There are some objects that I still need to include in the list. If toolstripitems is a control, then for whatever reason it doesn't get included into my list of controls